# mailto link opening indefinite number of new tabs

Tags: html

I was trying to create a  mail link in webpage and

I used this:

```
<a href="mailto:malavika@gmail.com" target="_blank">mailme</a>
```

when I click on the link indefinite new tabs are opening up.Can anybody tell me why this is happening

Comment: add HTML Code here

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Remove `target` Property

```
<a href="mailto:malavika@gmail.com">
```

Comment: May you could add a short description of why this removes the opening of n new tabs.

Comment: The most common reason to use `target=”_blank” is so that offsite links open in a separate tab. This allows a user to click on a reference and come back to it later without leaving the current page. It keeps visitors on your site longer and improves most of your metrics: bounce rate, conversion, pages visited

Read more: https://html.com/attributes/a-target/#ixzz5uThOVB2s

Comment: Please use the [edit] button as most users won't read the comments ;)

Answer (score 0):

remove target attribute and close a tag

```
<a href="mailto:malavika@gmail.com">mailme</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the target attribute

```
<a href="...">
```